# Error while getting database values into form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to get values from database and import them in checklist inside a form.
I am getting values with `CustomStudent.objects.all().values_list('sname')` but values are retrieved as list which gives error when submitting.

This is my forms.py

```
class WeeklyForm(forms.Form): 

    sname = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=CustomStudent.objects.all().values_list('sname'), required = False,  widget =forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple( attrs ={'class':' form-check-input'  ' form-check-inline'}))

    class_name = forms.CharField(widget= forms.Select(choices= [('1', 'UKG'), ('2', 'Class 1'), ('3', 'LKG'), ('4', 'Montessori') ] ,attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Select Class'}))

    fdate =  forms.DateField(initial = datetime.date.today() , required=False, widget =forms.DateInput( attrs ={'class': 'form-control' , 'placeholder' : ' Date ', 'name' : 'date'}))
    
    tdate =  forms.DateField(initial = datetime.date.today() , required=False, widget =forms.DateInput( attrs ={'class': 'form-control' , 'placeholder' : ' Date ', 'name' : 'date'}))

    objective = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'objective'}))
 
    target = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'target'}))
    
    how = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'how?'}))
    
    material = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'material required'}))

    support = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Any Support Required?'}))
```

This is my model

```
class CustomStudent(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField
    sname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    slname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 255, default = '')
```

I have tried adding `CustomStudent.objects.all().values_list('sname', flat=True)` which returns proper name instead of list in checkbox but causes a different error as 'Student' is not a valid value.

Student is an example name in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the `values_list("s_name")` part. For what you said, your query set is `CustomStudent.objects.all()`. There is an argument, `to_field_name`, that you can pass in the `ModelMultipleChoiceField` constructor. In order to show your Model in the selection, its `__str__` method will be called. You can change that by implementing:

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class CustomStudentModelField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.sname
```

So, in your form you would have:

```
    sname = CustomStudentModelField(queryset=CustomStudent.objects.all(), required = False,  widget =forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple( attrs ={'class':' form-check-input'  ' form-check-inline'}))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Your solution worked.